# pythonで1次元配列を昇順で並べ替え、かつ並べ替える前の要素の位置の導出

Tags: python

pythonで1次元配列を昇順で並べ替え、かつ並べ替える前の要素の位置も導出したいです。
sort関数だと前の要素の位置は残らないと思うので困っています。

```
li = [22, 50, 30, 46, 25, 12, 18, 19]
```

導出後

```
li1 = [12, 18, 19, 22, 25, 30, 46, 50]
li2 = [5, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

以上のような結果を求めたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

1行に詰め込むと

```
li1, li2 = [list(l) for l in zip(*sorted(zip(li, range(len(li))))]
```

でどうでしょう。`zip()` で各要素に配列での位置を追加した上でソート、"unzip" で２つに分けてます。"unzip" については
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip
を参考にして `zip(*zipped)` を使いました。求められてる答えが tuple じゃなくて list なのでさらに複雑になってますが、それがなければ

```
li1, li2 = zip(*sorted(zip(li, range(len(li))))
```

です。

どちらにしろ、用途によっては unzip しないままの方が使いやすいと思います。

Comment: ほとんど同じですけれど`li2, li1 = map(list, zip(*sorted(enumerate(li), key=lambda x:x[1])))`でいけますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。

Comment: `enumerate` で位置追加して、`lambda` か `operator.itemgetter` でソートキーを指定てソートする方が何をしているかが分かりやすいですね。

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> li1, li2 = sorted(li), sorted(range(len(li)), key=lambda k: li[k])
```